# '=' is working in place of 'eq'

Tags: perl, perl-module

Hi I am writing a perl script to accomplish some task.In my script I am using one if loop to compare two strings as shown below.

```
if($feed_type eq "SE"){
...........}
```

The above code is not giving me any warning but the output is not as I expected.
Instead of `'eq'` if I use `'='` I am getting a warning saying `expectng '==' but '=' is present`. But I am getting the expected output.
Ideally for string comparison I must use `'eq'` and for numbers `'=='`. In this case it's not working. Can anyone figure out what is the problem here?

More info:

This `if` loop is present in a subroutine. `$feed_type` is an input for this subroutine. I am reading the input as below:

```
my $feed_type=@_;
```

The problem is fixed. I just changed the assignemet statement of feed_type as below

```
my $feed_type=$_[0];
```

and it's reading the value as `SE` and the code is working.
but I still dont know why `my $feed_type=$_[0];` didn't work.

Comment: We cannot help without knowing what is inside of `$feed_type`. Print it before that line you showed and take a look. My best guess is it contains a newline character and the `eq` thus doesn't match. If you use `=` it will _assign_ `"SE"` to `$feed_type`, and that operation returns a true value, so Perl will execute the then-block.

Comment: @simbabque:I am assigning $feedtype to SE using below command. 
my $feed_type="SE"

Comment: What is that new line character? As I am a novice in perl I do not know much about this.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add a little more of your code. Where does `$feed_type` come from?

Comment: Hi, as you said I printed the value of feed_type.It's the value as 1. I have no clue why it's taking 1 even though I am sending 'SE' as input to the subroutine

Comment: $feed_type probably contains a newline

Comment: Look, we cannot just guess what happens. Either post your actual code, or write an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem so we can reproduce it. If there is input coming from a file, show a few relevant lines. If you feel uncomfortable showing production code, change variable names and strings. **Do not just retype some code here**. We are not able to help you like this.

Answer (score 4):

`=` might well work in place of `eq`, but not for the reason you think.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $test    = "fish";
my $compare = "carrot";

if ( $test = $compare ) {
    print "It worked\n";
}
```

Of course, the problem is - it'll *always* work, because you're testing the result of an assignment operation.*

* OK, sometimes assignment operations don't work - this is why some coding styles suggest testing `if ( 2 == $result )` rather than the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

This is about a core Perl concept: Context. Operators and functions work differently depending on context. In this case:

```
my $feed_type = @_;
```

You are assigning an array in scalar context to the variable. An array in scalar context returns *its size*, not the elements in it. For this assignment to work as you expect, you have to either directly access the scalar value you want, like you have suggested:

```
my $feed_type = $_[0];
```

...or you can put your variable in list context by adding parentheses:

```
my ($feed_type) = @_;
```

This has the benefit of allowing you to perform complex assignments, like this:

```
my ($first, $second, @rest) = @_;
```

So, in short, the problem was that your comparison that looked like this:

```
if($feed_type eq "SE")
```

Was actually doing this:

```
if(1 eq "SE")
```

And returning false. Which is true. Consider this self-documenting code:

```
sub foo {
    my $size = @_;
    if ($size == 1) {
         warn "You passed 1 argument to 'foo'\n";
         return;
    }
}
```

Which demonstrates the functionality you inadvertently used.

Answer (score 1):

= is used to assign the variable a value, so you would need '==' to compare numerical values and 'eq' for strings.

If it's complaining about not using '==', then it's because $feed_type is not a string.

I can't tell as there's no more code. Whatever $feed_type is set by you need to confirm it actually contains a string or if you're even referencing it correctly.

Comment: Your middle statement is incorrect on at least a couple levels.  `==` expects numbers, not strings.  If strings are found they are converted.  The warning that OP is seeing is because they are using assignment in a context that expects a Boolean & using `=` instead of `==` is an easy mistake to make.

Comment: Yeah you're right, but wrong on what I said, so maybe I wasn't clear.

OP was expecting $feed_type to be a string, it's not so the warning is suggesting you should use '=='. If it happens to be true so has the value of 1, then it's not a string and that explains it.